# Deleting tag: indexation

Tags: support, tags

While posting a question in the realm of [spatial indexing using quadtrees](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245247/quadtree-with-duplicates), I noticed the presence of both tag: [indexing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) and [indexation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexation). Though the latter is a French translation of the former, the English word *indexation* only has a meaning in economy.

Can we delete the *indexation* tag and keep *indexing* only instead?
This reminds me of the old *string* vs *string-manipulation* debate on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've retagged the questions (or in one case, deleted the tag).  The indexation tag should disappear with a nightly cleanup script of zombie tags.

Its much easier to do this on P.SE than SO - there were only a half dozen or so questions.